# Return Error or message of a view on another view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

There is a Login modal on _layout.cshtml page , so that user can login at any time or at any page. When the modal load ,we are appending a 'Login' view to the modal by  `$("#divModal").load("/Login/Index");`
while submitting the Form , Everything works fine.
But i was just wondering if there is any way to display the error or custom message like "Login failed" on the dialogBox on the same page except using Jquery ajax.

1) I tried to return view() but then it is redirecting the page to Login/Index page.
2) we can't use partial view then we have to pass LOgin Model with every other models.

Besides using Jquery ajax , is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JsonResult` if the error occurs. So you could write a custom action filter on the server which catches exception and transforms them into JSON response:

```
public class MyErrorHandlerAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new { success = false, error = filterContext.Exception.ToString() },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can add call back in your ajax call:

```
error: function(xhr) {
        try {
            // a try/catch is recommended as the error handler
            // could occur in many events and there might not be
            // a JSON response from the server
            var json = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            alert(json.errorMessage);
        } catch(e) { 
            alert('something bad happened');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sirwan , i got the idea. Returning as Json helped.